# French equivalents of "X puts the smile back on her face"

Tags: expressions, anglais, allemand

We were having a conversation in German, and I was wondering how the same idea is commonly/idiomatically expressed in French.

> Sie lässt sich nichts anmerken, aber so viel muss sie durchmachen. Mit ihnen zu spielen, **zaubert ihr** zumindest **immer ein Lächeln aufs Gesicht**.

We were talking about a child patient going through a lot due to her illness. Essentially, I wanted to express the idea of: "*Playing with other children has a way of **putting the smile** **back** **on her face***".

In German, one of the idiomatic phrasings above goes like: "*X makes a smile magically appear* / *conjures up a smile on your face*".

The first French phrasing that sprang to mind was:

> Ah, ce qu'on peut lui causer comme souci... Enfin, au moins, elle **retrouve toujours le sourire en** jouant avec eux.

... even if the subject is not the same.

Comment: Comme ça spontanément je dirais « ça lui redonne le sourire de jouer avec eux »

Comment: L'expression consacrée est « rendre le sourire », je crois.

Comment: @LPH Les deux se disent. Que veut dire « consacré » ? Qui consacre ?

Comment: C'est ce que l'on tend à dire le plus, ce qui semble identifier la chose nommée le plus universellement, de façon relative ou absolue ; ex. : Pierre Gavarni parlait des peintres qu'on lui avait annoncés comme devant prochainement sauter, l'expression consacrée pour la ruine des agents de change (GONCOURT, Journal, 1884, p. 347).

Comment: "Expression consacrée" est l'expression consacrée qui désigne l'expression que l'usage consacre.

Comment: @petitrien I think Laure wasn't asking about the meaning of "consacré" but what she meant was rather: "Who decided that 'rendre le sourire' would be *the* established expression for this? It's just one of the possible alternatives".

Answer (score 3):

**Redonner/rendre le sourire à quelqu'un**

> Ça lui redonne toujours le sourire de jouer avec les autres enfants.

> Jouer avec les autres enfants lui redonne toujours le sourire.

Spontanément j'emploie *redonner* mais *rendre* s'emploie tout autant.

[Redonner le sourire](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=QKk0XflEkK5r17mbwA0&q=redonner%20le%20sourire&oq=redonner%20le%20sourire&gs_l=psy-ab.12...4430.4430.0.5740.1.1.0.0.0.0.65.65.1.1.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.pBcAcU48BJg), [rendre le sourire](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rendre%20le%20sourire%22&tbm=bks&ei=8rA0XaClB5K_UMyXj8AC&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwig5umH1MbjAhWSHxQKHczLAygQ8NMDCIIB&biw=1853&bih=903&dpr=1)

En conversation informelle on emploiera plus facilement la [tournure impersonnelle avec « ça »](https://www.google.fr/search?lr=&as_qdr=all&ei=Fak0XZvfNvGDjLsP_pWSmAU&q=%22%C3%A7a%20lui%20redonne%20le%20sourire%22&oq=%22%C3%A7a%20lui%20redonne%20le%20sourire%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0..2094786...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.fbUZKFlY9jQ&ved=0ahUKEwjbvanIzMbjAhXxAWMBHf6KBFMQ4dUDCAo).

Deux titres d'articles de journal (il s'agit du même quotidien) en rapport avec la question :
[« Rendre le sourire aux enfants malades »](https://www.ouest-france.fr/bretagne/guerledan-22530/rendre-le-sourire-aux-enfants-malades-5965238)

[« Redonner le sourire aux enfants malades »](https://www.ouest-france.fr/bretagne/malestroit-56140/redonner-le-sourire-aux-enfants-malades-5459728)

« **[Retrouver](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=ubg0XbewHJK_Uv2KgeAD&q=%22retrouv%C3%A9+le+sourire%22&oq=%22retrouv%C3%A9+le+sourire%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...6444.7253.0.8630.2.2.0.0.0.0.67.133.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.AmFGG7HQ944)** le sourire » se dit aussi mais en général quand on n'exprime pas dans la phrase ce qui redonne le sourire

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion:

> *Jouer avec d'autres enfants a du moins la vertu* (or *le pouvoir*) *de lui faire retrouver le sourire.*